# Gatsby hot reloading does not reload in the Hello World starter project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, gatsby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### Description

I am following along with the instructions here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-one/
When I start the dev server and make a change to src/pages/index.js it is not hot reloaded in my browser.

---

### Steps to Reproduce

Using gatsby-cli:

- gatsby new hello-world https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world
- cd hello-world
- gatsby develop
- change the text inside of the div in src/pages/index.js

---

### Expected Result

Page would automatically reload with new text.

---

### Actual Result

Page would not change unless a manual refresh was applied in the browser.

---

### Specs

**OS**: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS running in WSL on Windows 10 Pro

**Node**: 12.12.0

**NPM**: 6.11.3

**Gatsby CLI**: 2.8.8

**Gatsby**: 2.17.6

**Browsers**: Chrome 77.0.3865.120, IE 11.1006.17134.0, Firefox 70.0

---

I've tried multiple browsers with the same result so I ran devtools in firefox and examined the console output when I make a change and I see this error:

```
The connection to http://localhost:8000/__webpack_hmr was interrupted while the page was loading. client.js:88
[HMR] Update check failed: hotDownloadManifest/</request.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:8000/commons.js:42:16
process-update.js:147
Error: Manifest request to /d528b21bff3fd2caa92d.hot-update.json timed out. bootstrap:41
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at http://localhost:8000/__webpack_hmr. client.js:88
```

I've also looked around on github and here and haven't found a solution to my problem. Any ideas on a workaround, solution, or insight into why this might not be working for me would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having same problems. Gatsby Develop hot reload was not working whenever I made changes to files, plus, Gatsby Develop was terribly slow to compile code and get the dev server up and running. I found out that if I create my Gatsby project in Linux directory structure instead of Windows, everything works out good and is blazing fast. So my solution was following.

Create your project in `/home/<your_username>` directory in WSL. Simply go to `/home/<your_username>` and make a folder there with `mkdir`; go to that folder and then run `Gatsby create my_project` command in that folder.

That way your project will reside in Linux directory structure, making everything run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar scenario today. Below steps made it work however warning message is persistent in the console.

1. Delete package.lock.json and node_modules folder
2. Delete the content present inside C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm and npm-cache
3. Do a `npm i`.

Answer (score 0):

Im running `gatsby develop` on windows. After trying many things, including wsl, npm clenaup etc, I realized that my antivirus *sophos* was blocking the webpack hot reload socket `__webpack_hmr`.

> All I had to do is to disable the antivirus for a while. ( You are free to uninstall it or maybe change to another one ).

hope it works for you ;)